# How to delete a sales order which is in sales order status?

Tags: openerp-7

I am a newbie to openerp. I have a sales order under the module 'sales' which is in 'Sales Order' status. The order number is 'SO019' . And i want to delete this sales order in the list.

When i tried to delete this sales order i got the following OpenErp Warning

```
Invalid Action!

In order to delete a confirmed sales order, you must cancel it.
To do so, you must first cancel related picking for delivery orders.
```

But i have no option to cancel this delivery in the 'warehouse/Delivery Orders'
Instead of this i have the following two options

1. Print Delivery Slip
2. Return Products

When i click onto the Return products i am getting the following warning

```
Warning!

No products to return (only lines in Done state and not fully returned yet can be returned)!
```

Is there anyway that i can delete this sales order(SO019) in the sales orders list?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the Confirm Sale Order, The Delivery Order is made. So first you need to cancel first delivery order. In Delivery Order has button name `Cancel Transfer.`

**If your delivery order is in `Delivered state` than you can not delete Sale Order.**

At first time for **Delivery Order**, click on `Return Product`. The reverse entry is create. You can see that entry in **Incoming Shipment**. for example **IN/001-OUT/002-return** entry is created.

Now At Second time you click on Return Product from the Same Delivery order as you do above step than you got your above warning. Because you can not return product twice for same Delivery Order.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes it is in delivered state. So you are saying that i cannot delete this sale order. rite?

Comment: yes. If you Return Product the back order will come into picture.

Comment: In my question i said that when clicking onto the Return Products i am getting another warning. what exactly your point?

Comment: yes. you get above warning because you can not return product for Same Delivery order. Check your incoming shipment at their entry made like "IN/00001-OUT/0003-return"

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer ? In your first comment you said that if i return the product it will work. But i have already said that i am getting a warning when i return the product.  What i have to do in the incoming shipment ? Is there any way that i can delete this sale order? If there is a solution please elaborate that answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the column status shows 'Sales Order' that means your invoice for that order is created and you can not delete sale order until you delete invoice related to it or order is cancelled.
To delete sale order with status 'Sale order',

**Short way:**

1] Just click on 'Cancel Order' [and its automatically deleted]
(But invoice related to it is go to cancel state and is visible)

**Long way**

1] Go to  Accounting-> customer invoice

2]Cancel invoice for your sale order.[Invoice status changed to 'Cancelled']

3]Delete that invoice [More-Delete]

4]Go to Sale->Sale Order [Now status is Changed to 'Invoice Exception']

5]Now click on your sale order and then 'Cancel Order' [Now its automatically deleted]